# Receiving Build Error When Trying To Build EFModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

As the title says, when I am trying to build the DLL for my EF model, I am receiving the following build error:

> Error  9   An Exception was thrown while processing the template.  The following Exception was thrown:
>   System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.IDebugTransformationRun.get_Errors()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessTemplateImplementation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String content, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String className, String classNamespace)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToSQL10.tt   0   0   Miscellaneous Files

I am using Entity Framework version 6.1.3 and the odd thing is that I have another copy of the same project elsewhere in my solution and it does not get this error.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this build error?

Answer (score 1):

After looking around elsewhere, I developed a hunch that the problem was being caused by my Entity Framework installation.  I went ahead and opened up the NuGet Package Manager console and ran the command:

> Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework.

After waiting for EF to reinstall, I restarted Visual Studio. Upon restarting I was able to build my EF Model project without any errors. Hopefully this helps anyone else who runs into the same problem.